# Deleting a Page or Document in Sitecore 9.2

Tags: content-management

Is it still necessary to publish the parent item after deleting a page or PDF in Sitecore to remove it from the website or database?

I found it to be necessary in v7.2, but is it still?

Comment: In short; yes´..

Comment: My developer isn't convinced. What's the long version.

Comment: Yes it is necessary.